# Multiple python module import error in maven build

Tags: python, python-2.7, maven, jython, robotframework

I am executing robot testcases from maven build. Now these testcases need many external python modules.
When I execute them directly(`pybot`), everything works fine.

But when I execute them via maven, it fails for the external python modules.

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/xyz/robot/tf2jan/Tests/CLI/mycli/mycli_resources.txt': Importing test library '/home/xyz/robot/tf2jan/lib/rest/JsonValidator.py' failed: ImportError: No module named jsonselect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xyz/robot/tf2jan/lib/rest/JsonValidator.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jsonselect import jsonselect
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /home/xyz/Downloads/python-jsonpath-rw
  /home/xyz/Downloads/ply-3.10
  /home/xyz/.m2/repository/org/robotframework/robotframework/3.0.2/Lib
  /home/xyz/.m2/repository/org/robotframework/robotframework/3.0.2/robotframework-3.0.2.jar/Lib
```

I do have option of adding them in the maven plugin configuration using `extraPathDirectories` like this:

```
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.7</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>acceptance-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <skip>${skipRobotTests}</skip>
                                    <testCasesDirectory>/home/xyz/robot/tf2jan/Tests/CLI/mycli</testCasesDirectory>
                                    <variableFiles>/home/xyz/robot/tf2jan/etc/environments/mycli_env.py</variableFiles>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/robotframework-reports/</outputDirectory>
                                    <tests>mycli_help_usage</tests>
                                    <extraPathDirectories>
                                        <extraPathDirectory>/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages</extraPathDirectory>
                                        <extraPathDirectory>/home/xyz/Downloads/python-jsonpath-rw</extraPathDirectory>
                                        <extraPathDirectory>/home/xyz/Downloads/ply-3.10</extraPathDirectory>
                                    </extraPathDirectories>
                                    <externalRunner>
                                        <excludeDependencies>false</excludeDependencies>
                                        <jvmArgs>
                                            <jvmArg>${surefireArgLine}</jvmArg>
                                        </jvmArgs>
                                    </externalRunner>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
               </plugin>
```

But with this solution, I'll end up adding too many modules in the path, which will complicate the pom file. 
Is there any configuration to resolve these modules dependencies automatically or any other shorter solution?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest, as you don't have dependency management for Python libraries in Maven, is to :

- Put your libraries in the default lib directory of Python
- Add to your PYTHONPATH (since it is checked by Maven, see the output `PYTHONPATH:`) the location of your libraries

  **Edit** If you want to avoid having to install manually to your CI boxes the dependency, you could try this maven plugin:

  ```
  <plugin>
              <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download- plugin</groupId>
              <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.0</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>install-a-dependency</id>
                      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>wget</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <url>the_dependency_url</url>
                          <unpack>true</unpack>
                          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jbpm-3.1.4</outputDirectory>
                          <md5>df65b5642f33676313ebe4d5b69a3fff</md5>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

See https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin

Comment: Yes, but for that one has to know what are all external modules required. Think of a scenario when a new module dependency has been added in test-suite, the developer can add it on his local PYTHONPATH but the CI system wouldn't be knowing about that addition and will fail the build.

Comment: But if you add something like "somePath/external-lib-directories" to your PYTHONPATH and then every external libraries is put Inside this folder, wouldn't it work? Or is it just not something you can do in your environment?

Comment: This will work, and this I can certainly do on my local environment but the CI boxes where the build happens and the test-suites get triggered are different boxes and are not taken care by the development team. We shouldn't be asking them to add new module everytime we add a new dependency.

Comment: What about having maven automatically downloading the dependency and putting it somewhere? (I edited my post)

Comment: But you have to add multiple entries in the pom, which will make the pom file very large and again one has to be very careful and add those dependencies in the pom file. It is a better solution though.

Comment: I would argue that as long as you keep it in a separate pom the size would not matter too much as it would stay readable for other members no? Also if you were adding a lot of  java dependencies, you would get a huge pom

Comment: It is a solution but what I am looking for is if could automatically resolve those dependencies. like when I execute these test-suites from CLI, It didn't fail for these dependencies. In my python home, these external modules are not there as well. These must be something.